# Validar si la key del objeto 19 es igual a la primera letra del String

Tags: javascript, objeto

Lo que sucede es que tengo declarado un objeto con las letras del abecedario dentro de una función, a esta función se le pasara un *String* y quiero validar si la key del objeto 19 es igual a la primera letra del *String*. La key 19 del objeto es "t" y la primera letra del *String* es "t", pero me sale como que esto no es cierto.

Mi código:

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
    var obj = [ {"a" : 1}, {"b" : 2}, {"c":3}, {"d":4} ,{"e":5}, {"f":6}, {"g":7} , {"h":8}, {"i":9}, {"j":10}, {"k":11},
{"l":12}, {"m":13}, {"n":14}, {"o":15}, {"p":16}, {"q":17}, {"r":18}, {"s":19}, {"t":20}, {"u":21}, {"v":22}, {"x":23},
{"y":24}, {"z":25 }];

    console.log(Object.keys(obj[19]))
    console.log(Object.keys(obj[19]) === text[0])
}

alphabetPosition("the sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
```

Comment: [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) devuelve un arreglo y, de hecho, se puede ver cuando lo envías a la consola, aparece `["t"]`. Para comparar correctamente, haz referencia a ese elemento agregando `[0]` después del método: `console.log(Object.keys(obj[19])[0] === text[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

Ahí te lo corregí

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  var obj = [
    { a: 1 },
    { b: 2 },
    { c: 3 },
    { d: 4 },
    { e: 5 },
    { f: 6 },
    { g: 7 },
    { h: 8 },
    { i: 9 },
    { j: 10 },
    { k: 11 },
    { l: 12 },
    { m: 13 },
    { n: 14 },
    { o: 15 },
    { p: 16 },
    { q: 17 },
    { r: 18 },
    { s: 19 },
    { t: 20 },
    { u: 21 },
    { v: 22 },
    { x: 23 },
    { y: 24 },
    { z: 25 }
  ];

  console.log(Object.keys(obj[19])[0], text, text[0]);
  console.log(Object.keys(obj[19])[0] === text[0]);
}

alphabetPosition("the sunset sets at twelve o' clock.");
```

Te faltó hacerle sub[0] a los Object.keys pues esa function devuelve un array!